# Windows 10 - How to merge two partitions?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I have an `F:` drive and an `E:` drive, which are both empty. I want to merge them into a single `E:` drive. How would I go about doing this?

Here is my current layout

[image: My current layout]

So from this, I think it should be that `/dev/sda1` is my EFI partition, `/dev/sda2` must be the recovery partition, `/dev/sda3` is the partition with the C: drive and the rest are my D: through F: drives. I have nothing stored on F: and E:, as I said.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot indicating the current partition layout of the disk.  This information must be provided in order for any answer to be submitted.  Please do not submit a comment, instead edit your question, with the required information necessary to answer your question

Comment: @Ramhound I have provided a screenshot

Comment: Your screenshot doesn’t contain the information required to answer your question.  It doesn’t contain the partition layout, it’s only half of the information, contained within Disk Management. If you attempting to dual boot you need to specify that fact in your question

Comment: _/dev/sda2 must be the recovery partition_ That's an assumptions, and since altering partitions is the absolute easier and quickest way to lose data, please make sure of what's where.

Comment: That is all the information contained in the disk management utility, other than capacity and free space

Comment: @GuityLoiker - You didn’t provide the pretty graphic at the bottom of the window.  *Just provide the entire window instead of a cropping the image*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **E:** and **F:** are *truly* empty, you can delete **F:**, and then expand the space used by **E:** based on [this article](https://www.andyrathbone.com/2010/01/06/managing-disk-space-by-deleting-one-partition-and-expanding-another/).

However, please make a complete backup of your valuable data first. Verify it is a good backup. Then make *another* backup to a different external drive or cloud, and verify that, before starting the wood chipper.

Right-click the Windows icon START button
[image: START button icon]

Choose **Disk Management**
[image: Right-click menu from START]

Right-click on **F:**, pick **Delete Volume** from the pop-up menu, then choose **Yes** when asked to confirm.

Right-click on the **E:** partition and select **Extend Volume** from the pop-up menu.

When the Extend Volume Wizard appears, click **Next** at the opening screen, then click **Next** again to expand the **E:** partition to fill the room left by the now-deleted **F:** partition.

Choose **Finish** to tell the Extend Volume Wizard to complete extending the **E:** partition to fill the available space.